# Is there a de-facto standard datatype for 3d vectors in Semantic Web languages(RDF/Owl/etc.)

Tags: types, rdf, owl, semantic-web

I need to represent a typical physics vector (such as a position or velocity) in a semantic language (RDF, OWL, JSON-LD, etc.).  Being a compound data type, it is typically recommended that this be modeled as a blank node with 3 xsd:float properties on it.  However, the behavior of this is very unnatural for my application, because the vector is really being treated as a data type (rather than an object) at every other step of the process.  They never behave like an object in any way (except for the purposes of being modeled as a blank node with 3 properties)

It seems like this should not be a new problem, so I'm curious if there is a de facto data type which represents this.  I'm expecting it to be a string of numbers, separated by spaces, commas, or some other delimiter like `"10.0 20.0 30.0"^^my:VectorType`, because that seems like it would be the most natural way to represent this data.

I can  make my own datatype, and specify the mapping from literals to values myself, but it seems like this should be such a common desire that there might be a consensus on the datatype to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of doing so. In OWL I recommend using an indexer for this. You can find an example of OWL indexer here: https://sourceforge.net/p/meloproject/code/ci/master/tree/OWL/examples/indexer.owl

Comment: Thank you for the approach and the link.  For the particular case of trying to handle a simple 3-vector, indexers are probably overkill.  But I have other problems that I'm trying to tackle where indexers would be a perfect fit, so thank you!  I'm definitely going to be applying this pattern!

Comment: When it comes to multidimensional vectors, matrices, their transpositions and other operations, the indexer approach in OWL can be a big asset.